# I want to learn about TensorFlowInferenceInterface which is used to create tensorflow apps. What sources can trusted?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I am working on project Audio classifier app. I am beginner in java Also if some one can help me figure out how to extract MFFC features from audio signal I would like give them credit,also provide me contact details if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

In Android, you can use [TensorFlow Lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite) , a lightweight solution for TensorFlow.

1. You can convert a TensorFlow model, or Keras model to a TF Lite model ( .tflite ). See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert).
2. This TF Lite model could be inferenced on an Android or iOS device using the TF Lite's Java and Swift API.
3. It may not support some layers like LSTM or BatchNormalization. Dense and all Conv layers work well.
4. Another method is using Tensorflow Mobile.
5. TensorFlow Mobile runs a protocol buffers file ( .pb ). It has been deprecated but can be still used. But, Google suggests its developers to use TF Lite.

You can find a complete tutorial [here](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/building-pok%C3%A9dex-in-android-using-tensorflow-lite-and-firebase-cc780848395).

Comment: I appreciate your answer Mr. Shubham Panchal.I am making an app that records an audio for a fixed duration and extract MFCC features from the audio signal and then feed it to the neural network. I am not using LSTM or BatchNormalization , it contains Dense and all Conv layers. If it is possible to extract features and then pass it to the neural network by using tensorflow light then please let me know

Comment: TensorFlow Lite could be used to only make predictions from a pretrained model. It cannot train a model on a Android device since it has memory limitations. So, you need to train a model in TensorFlow ( Python ) to extract features and then convert it to a TF Lite model. Load that model in Android and make predictions from it.

Comment: Bro I don't want to train the network. Extract MFCCs features in java and then feed input to the model and get output . Please if any options available please let me know.

Comment: In Java, I don't think any options are available. Sorry.